# Precompiling Views using MvcBuildViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to ship pre-compiled views. I've seen a few questions regarding specifying

Changing the following in the csproj

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>.
```

and

and modifying the web.config (since i am using entityframework)

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".edmx"/>
      </buildProviders>
 </compilation>
```

it now takes longer to compile which i was expecting however im not sure if it is working correctly

1. can i presume i am right in saying that if configured correctly it should actually build the views into the binary rather than just doing a precompilation validation?
2. if true then should i prevent the webdeployment from shipping the cshtmls? will the presence of them onsite cause a recompile?
3. if so this should result in a faster start time for deployed mvc applications? as they don't need to compile the views?
4. should I add false to the csproj as well? i saw an article which suggested i should change it from true to false, but it isn't present  in my csproj.

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RazorGenerator](https://nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc) seemed to be the only option to my original question which was to ship compiled views as binaries.

Answer (score 4):

> can i presume i am right in saying that if configured correctly it should actually build the views into the binary rather than just doing
>   a precompilation validation?

No.

> if true then should i prevent the webdeployment from shipping the
>   cshtmls? will the presence of them onsite cause a recompile?

No, `cshtml` files must be present when you ship.

> if so this should result in a faster start time for deployed mvc
>   applications? as they don't need to compile the views?

No, in Release mode there's an optimization made by Razor which automatically will cache the location of views and once it parses them it doesn't reparse on subsequent requests.

So, the moral of the story is that you could enable the MvcBuildViews option in Release mode so that your build server could detect any potential errors during the continuous integration build of the project. In Debug mode I keep it disabled because it slows down building.

Comment: Ok so the only way to get built binaries is to use a custom package i.e. https://nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc

Comment: What do you mean by *build binaries*? What are you trying to achieve? You want to embed Razor views into assemblies and reuse them in multiple projects? If this is so, then, yes, you will have to use a custom virtual path provider.

Comment: binary (as in the dll's) having the views compiled into the binary dll.

Comment: oh, you need a custom virtual path provider for that. The Razor view engine has nothing built-in that will allow you to read views embedded into assemblies. By default it will look for them on the file system.